# Custom Function for JSON API request

Tags: jquery, json, api

Hi I am requesting data from a API and I want to add the result to a Div with a specific ID.
It worked just fine but when I tried to create a custom function for it it stopped working.

It has got something to do with my fullrequest variable. but I got no clue how to do it.

My html:

```
<script>
OctoGET0('GET', '/api/connection', 'current.state' , '#play')
</script>
```

My jquery:

```
function webAPI(method, location , data, request , id ) {   
   var fullrequest = 'response.'+request;

    $.ajax({
      url: Url + location ,
      type: method,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: setHeader,
      data: data,
      success: (function(response) { $(id).html(fullrequest)})      
    })
```

[EDIT]

the JSON i'm requesting

```
{
  "current": {
"baudrate": null, 
"state": "Closed", 
"port": null
  }, 
  "options": {
"portPreference": null, 
"autoconnect": false, 
"baudrates": [
  250000, 
  230400, 
  115200, 
  57600, 
  38400, 
  19200, 
  9600
], 
"ports": [
  "/dev/ttyAMA0"
], 
"baudratePreference": null
  }
}
```

some requests go deeper than 2 tiers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do but your current code is going to always append "response.current.state" to the #play div. I think you more likely wanted to append the response from the API concatenated with the request into the div. furthermore you should not have parenthesis wrapping your success function. End result would be this:

[EDIT]

`function webAPI(method, location , data, request , id ) {

    $.ajax({
      url: Url + location ,
      type: method,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: setHeader,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) { 
          var returnValue = response;
         var parts = request.split('.');
         for (var i=0;i < parts.length;i++) {
            if (typeof returnValue == 'Object') {
                returnValue = returnValue[parts[i]];
            }
         }
         $(id).html(returnValue);
      }

    });`

This would obviously have to be tested and reworked to fit your needs. The main issue is that you are trying to access an object property as a string which does not work

Comment: I would like the response be variable.

this is what is needs to look like.
html(response.current.state)

Comment: Hmmm I not sure what im doing wrong when I fit it in my js the only response that i get is [Object Object]
added the JSON i'm requesting data from to my question